# Videos are playing too fast using OpenCV and PyQT5

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pyqt5

My GUI is able to play videos automatically when selected in the `QListWidget`. However, instead of normal speed, the videos play very fast. I use 720p Mp4 videos as examples and are placed in a certain folder. I tried using `cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS` and `cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE`, but they are both not working. I am using `pyqtSignal` in the `QThread` and the `convert_cv_qt` function which I saw in other guides. **How do I play the videos in normal speed / frame rate?**

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread


class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.get_file_dir = self.parent().file_dir #Get the file_dir from UI_MainWindow

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.get_file_dir)
        
        while True:
            ret, cv_img = cap.read()
            if ret:
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)
        cap.release()


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUI()
    
    def setupUI(self):
        MainWindow.resize(1720, 863)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(True)
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.videoimage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.videoimage.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 1280, 720))
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.tab)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1290, 60, 391, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.itemclick)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(0, "Testing")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.listvideos()
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def listvideos(self):
        file_extension = ['avi','mp4','mov']
        arr = os.listdir('D:\\Files\\VSCODE\\APPS\\HDTS\\videos')
        for i in arr:
            for fe in file_extension:
                    if i[-3:] == fe:
                        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(str(i))
                        self.listWidget.addItem(item)

    def itemclick(self):
        try:
          self.thread.terminate()
        except:
          print("Nothing to terminate!")

        item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
        self.file_dir = 'D:\\Files\\VSCODE\\APPS\\HDTS\\videos\\' + item.text()
        print(self.file_dir)        
        self.thread = VideoThread(self)
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        self.thread.start()
    
    
    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.videoimage.setPixmap(qt_img)
    
    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(1280, 720, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(p)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please consider that your implementation of `setupUi` is not very good, most importantly because it operates on a *global* `MainWindow` (using globals is generally considered bad practice, caused by poor implementation), but also because it creates possible issues with the classes and instances. Really, don't do that. `Ui_MainWindow` is already subclassing from QMainWindow, so you should **only** use that, without creating another instance of QMainWindow; then change all references to `MainWindow` in `setupUi` to `self`.

Comment: I will try my best to follow your advice as I learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use VideoCapture with a file if you call "cap.read()" you will obtain the next frame on the video, regardless of its actual framerate. Hence, you should use a "msleep" every time you capture a frame:

```
def run(self):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.get_file_dir)
    
    while True:
        ret, cv_img = cap.read()
        if ret:
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)
        self.msleep(1000//30) # You can change 30 with 60 if you need 60 fps.
    cap.release()
```

Comment: I tried it with the same indention but it produces an error:
`TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  wait(self, msecs: int = ULONG_MAX): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  wait(self, QDeadlineTimer): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'`

Comment: @gentales17 I edited my answer, try with this

Comment: it  is still playing too fast. I tried 30-1000 and there are no changes at all.
`self.wait(1000//30)`, `self.wait(1000//60)`, `self.wait(1000//100)` and `self.wait(1000//1000)`

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. I just changed the value from 30- to 60 (as you suggested), even up to 1000 but there are no changes at all. I also tried changing the indention but it didn't work either. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: @gentales17 I edited once again, try this version. I think that "wait" was not the proper method to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, you can edit number in cv2.waitkey() to speed up or down the videos.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread
import threading
import time


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUI()
        self.playing = False
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.stop_event.clear()

    def setupUI(self):
        MainWindow.resize(1720, 863)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(True)
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.videoimage = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.videoimage.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 1280, 720))
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.tab)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1290, 60, 391, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.itemclick)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(0, "Testing")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.listvideos()
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def listvideos(self):
        file_extension = ['avi', 'mp4', 'mov']
        arr = os.listdir('E:\\Steve\\Python_learning\\pyQT5')
        for i in arr:
            for fe in file_extension:
                if i[-3:] == fe:
                    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(str(i))
                    self.listWidget.addItem(item)

    def itemclick(self):
        print('1')
        if self.playing:
            try:
                print('3')
                self.stop_thread()
                print(self.stop_event.isSet())
            except:
                print("Nothing to terminate!")
        print('2')
        #self.start_thread_flag()
        print(self.stop_event.isSet())
        item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
        self.file_dir = 'E:\\Steve\\Python_learning\\pyQT5\\' + item.text()
        print(self.file_dir)
        self.play_videos()
        # self.thread = VideoThread(self)
        # self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.run)
        # self.thread.start()
    def stop_thread(self):

        self.stop_event.set()

    def start_thread_flag(self):
        self.stop_event.clear()

    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.videoimage.setPixmap(qt_img)
    def play_videos(self):

        try:

            self.reading_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
            self.reading_thread.daemon = True
            self.reading_thread.start()
        except Exception as e:

            print(' Videos Player export an exception \n ' + str(e))
    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(1280, 720, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(p)
    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.file_dir)
        print('play start')
        print(self.stop_event.isSet())
        while True :

            ret, cv_img = cap.read()
            if ret:
                self.playing= True
                print(f'playing = {self.playing}')
                self.update_image(cv_img)
                cv2.waitKey(40)
            if self.stop_event.isSet():
                self.playing = False
                self.stop_event.clear()
                raise Exception("Sorry, this thread must be stoped")
        cap.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```